# How to avoid blocking of website hosted on Kubernetes

Tags: web, kubernetes, dns, record, blocking

Imagine having a website that being constantly blocked (e.x. any of the pirate movie sites). How they get through the block? I assume they being blocked by DNS record and need to contact local ISP to unblock.
My questions:

1. If the app is running on Kubernetes then IP address of the Ingress Controller is bind with DNS record. When the blocking occurs, does it occurs on DNS record? Is it working solution to start new Ingress Controller and bind the same DNS record to the new IP address?
2. Basically how the blocked website appears to be functional again under the same DNS record? Do they have good lawyers and just negotiating this block with ISP provider?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a website that is being blocked repeatedly, I would not be asking how to get around it -- I would be asking what is my site doing to be getting blocked in the first place. Sounds like the site owner (if it's not you) may be doing something against their provider and/or ISP's Terms of Service, and if they're getting blocked repeatedly, they are probably not learning their lesson.